# How to change text selector color?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I was adding some text in text View and I wanted to select it but I there's a problem with selector color because it's red. How to make it default blue?

[image]

Comment: `yourTextView.tintColor = myColor` Did you modified it?

Comment: Yes, it's working! Thank you!